# How to use Express routes with React.js frontend?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

Can I use Express routing for sending the content of the pages? In classic HTML, you can do:

```js
app.get("/admin", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("admin.html"); // or res.render() for templating engines like EJS
});
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to use Express routing for serving the **React* pages*. The only way I found was to use React Router, which technically gets the job done, but then I can't do anything else on the server-side, like validating the login. I could technically make an API endpoint on the server-side for that and then request it within the React JSX page itself, however, that'd be inconvenient for many reasons:

1. Having the requests be sent only after the page, which means tons of loading indicating and possible issues like the user being able to see the content he should not be able to see at all.
2. Most of the "on-page-visit" API requests would need to be protected with keys, like the Authorization key
3. If the API request is done anywhere on the client-side, the keys are insecure and also the response can be manually altered by the user which creates huge security violations.

If there was a React renderer for Express, in which you could render a React JSX file directly from the page (e.g. `res.render("page.jsx")`) which would compile React and send the pure HTML, that'd be great! But of course, I haven't been able to find such and I doubt there are any.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a react page". There are only HTML pages that load React bundles, which are just javascript `<script>` loads like any other JS code. Which is also your answer: your server generates the HTML response for page URL requests. That HTML then does the same thing it does if there's no server at all: load css/scripts as needed.

Comment: @nortex_dev Why isn't that you create this page on React and when a user hits that certain route in server you can then redirect easy from react and display contents that you wanted easily for sure

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but only only with the bundled appilcation. You simply send the index.html you find in the build folder of your react application.

Would look like this:
Assuming that is you express index.js & that the react application lives in a "client" directory of your applicaiton.

```
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
```

Comment: Isn't this type of configuration applicable when your React app and Node app are running on the same url(This is most likely in production depending on the deployer obviously)? If not can you please explain how the routes will be differentiated  with regards to maybe route **A** is to be maintained in Node and route **B** sent to React

Comment: What if I want one route to be server-side protected, while keeping others normal?

Comment: @nortex_dev You can achieve this trough authentication middleware in express. If you like JWTs look into express-jwt :) It should say how to secure indidvidual routes there.
Similar things are possible with sessions :)

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane Its depends how you deplay it. If you serve your react app via an CDN or configure nginx to do this this would not be nessesary. But if you do like above you can differentiate the routes by having the react appilication routed to "\*" and other routes handled by more specific routes. But you could also route your react application through something like "/react/*".

Comment: Okay makes sense I assumed this config is applicable when you in production mode where for example when web app is deployed on heroku you can have both front-end and back-end using same baseUrl

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane The code i posted is actually just copy pasted from an a web app i deployed on heroku. So exactly the use case youve mentioned :D